# Simple, intuitive high school level explanation of spectral theorem and the covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, principal-component-analysis

Ive been trying to understand spectral theorem ( a symmetric matrix has n independent, orthogonal eigenvectors ), but the proof seems to be way above my level. Similarly, ive been trying to realize the geometric significance of the covariance matrix and why its eigenvectors are the directions of maximum variance, and the eigenvalues are the magnitude of variance. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there isn't much we can do about the level of the spectral theorem. I suspect there's a reason why it isn't taught in third grade. I'm afraid you'll have to work on *your* level, instead. Simply you need professional tools to work in any profession.

Comment: @ProfessorVector i dont necessarily need to proof the theorem, just provide an intuitive explanation of why it works. do you mind perhaps guiding me to any such sources? all the stuff online i find is just hard math, and it makes my brain hurt.

Comment: It's a mathematical theorem, so as soon as you give a mathematically rigorous definition of "intuitive", I might give it a thought.

Comment: I wouldn't worry aboout intuitively understanding it too much. I know that this might not be a satisfactory answer but I think the spectral theorem is a classical example of a result which is incredibly useful in many fields of maths that can use methods of linear algebra but it isn't necessarily an "interesting", i.e. self-motivated result. Maybe I'm missing something, but I've been using it in many ways without having an intuitive understanding of why it's true. That's just how high level maths works sometimes.

Comment: The origins of eigenvector analysis of symmetric matrices started with the study of infinite-dimensional diagonalization of differential operators arising out of separation of variables of the wave equation for a stretched metal wire. If you can make that clear to third graders, then you deserve a teaching award.